# Adding a button with innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add html code inside a `<span id="options"></span>` so I'm trying to use this:

```
function editTextArea(element) {
   var options = document.getElementById("options");
   options.innerHTML = options.innerHTML + "Cols: <input type='text' id='colsTextArea' maxlength='3' /><br>Rows: <input type='text' id='rowsTextArea' maxlength='2' /><br><button type='button' onclick='updateTextArea('" + element.id + "')' >Add</button><br>";
}
```

But this is what I got,

```
<button type="button" onclick="updateTextArea(" textarea0')'="">Agregar</button>
```

My problem is with the quotes, so I later tried using createElement("button"), but now I can't add the onclick attribute.

I'm not using jQuery, so it would be nice to have a solution without it.

Comment: Manipulating the dom without a library like jQuery will never work on all browsers unless you spend hours and hours on optimization - like this problem. I bet it would work with jQuery.

Comment: @Marc seriously , that overdoes the level of sarcasmn :-)

Comment: Does it? Ok, I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use different quotes for the function call to updateTextArea than you do for the onclick attribute. You can't do onclick='alert('hi');', because the single quote terminates the onclick attribute.

```
function editTextArea(element) {
   var options = document.getElementById("options");
   options.innerHTML = options.innerHTML + "Cols: <input type='text' id='colsTextArea' maxlength='3' /><br>Rows: <input type='text' id='rowsTextArea' maxlength='2' /><br><button type='button' onclick='updateTextArea(" + '"' + + element.id + '"' + ")' >Add</button><br>";
}
```

You should definately consider doing this at least with the proper DOM API calls. You are right to try document.createElement

To set an onclick, do something like this:

```
var button = document.createElement('button').
button.onclick = function(){
 alert('I was clicked');
}
```

Comment: Do you think if it is possible to do it within html like the following using Angular: 
in ts file:
HTMLstring = '<button type="button">a button</button>';

in HTML
<div [innerHTML] = "HTMLstring"> </div>

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with escaping the quotes also:

```
options.innerHTML = options.innerHTML + "Cols: <input type='text' id='colsTextArea' maxlength='3' /><br>Rows: <input type='text' id='rowsTextArea' maxlength='2' /><br><button type='button' onclick=\"updateTextArea(\'" + id + "\')\" >Add</button><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are going with second option you can use setAttribute() method.

`var ele =  document.createElement('button');

ele.setAttribute('onclick','method_name');`